# How do I get my numbers in python to show up with $?

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm in high school and I'm trying out python for the first time. I want my equation to print with $ before the numbers. This is my code right now:

```
revenue = 98456
costs = 45000
profit = revenue - costs
print(profit)
```

My professor said that you can do a thing where you strip the strings and put them back on but I'm really confused with how to do that with $. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: ```print(f"${profit}")```?

Comment: Since you are new to python, I suggest that you do some research and try things out on your own first.  Refer to the documentation, look for similar questions or just ask your professor.  Posting a question here will give you a direct answer and you will miss out on a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use string formatting:

```
print(f"${profit}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
revenue = 98456
costs = 45000
profit = revenue - costs
print("$ " +str(profit))
```

will give

```
$ 53456
```

Answer (score 0):

See the locale module.

This does currency (and date) formatting.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
'English_United States.1252'
>>> locale.currency( 188518982.18 )
'$188518982.18'
>>> locale.currency( 188518982.18, grouping=True )
'$188,518,982.18'
```

Some examples: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/6701/locale.currency